# Find the column with biggest sum in matrix and print it out

Tags: arrays, c, matrix

I am writing a program that you enter the n rows x m columns matrix, and then find the column with the biggest sum and print that column out,i am trying to print that column out. Any help would be appreciated.

For example:

```
  Input            Output
4 5 6 4 0 0          4
4 2 3 2 2 2          4
6 5 2 1 0 1          6
```

My result:

```
  Input            Output
4 5 6 4 0 0         
4 2 3 2 2 2          14
6 5 2 1 0 1
```

And there is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void Entermatrix(int a[][50], int &n,int &m)
{
 printf("Enter matrix's rows: ");
 scanf("%d",&n);
 printf("Enter matrix's columns: ");
 scanf("%d",&m);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<m;j++){
            printf("A[%d][%d]= ",i,j);
            scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
    }
}

void Printmatrix(int a[][50], int n, int m)
{
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<m;j++) {
            printf("%5d",a[i][j]);
   }
    printf("\n");}
}

void Columnwithbiggestsum(int a[][50],int n,int m)
{
    int max=0;
    
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        int sum=0;
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            sum = sum+a[j][i];
        }
        if (sum >max){
            max=sum;
        }   
    }
    printf ("The biggest sum by column is: %d",max);
}

int main()
{
 int a[50][50],n,m;
 Entermatrix(a,n,m);
 Printmatrix(a,n,m);
 Columnwithbiggestsum(a,n,m);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're only storing the maximum sum, but not the column it occurred in.  So you have no way of knowing which column to output when it comes time to deliver the result.

Comment: You have not described a specific error or incorrect behaviour. What specific problem do you have? At a minimum please give the exact input, expected result and actual result.

Comment: yes, i'm trying to figure it out, do you have some idea or suggest how i do it please ?

Comment: no, i don't have any error, my code run perfectly, but i don't know how to print the column that have the biggest sum in the matrix, so i up it here

Comment: I just told you what you're not doing, indicating that you need to do it.

Comment: Ok thank you so much sir!

Comment: i'm using DEVC++

Comment: ok i got it, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the function "Columnwithbiggestsum" you can keep another variable to store the Column number with the highest sum.

once you have column number you can Iterate in the matrix to print the content of that column.

Modified your code to print the column

```
void Columnwithbiggestsum(int a[][50],int n,int m)
{
    int max=0;
    int columnNo=0;
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        int sum=0;
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            sum = sum+a[j][i];
        }
        if (sum >max){
            max=sum;
            columnNo = i;
        }   
    }
   
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf ("%d \n", a[i][columnNo]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Problem solved, thank you so much! you made my day.

Comment: BitMask, with `"%d \n"`, why print a space between the  `int` and the `'\n'`?

Comment: yes you are right no extra space is needed there, but I added it  for better readability, you can remove it if you want.